# Greatest common divisor theorem proof

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I wanted to prove an algebraic theorem and therefore I would need a statement like the following:

> In a commutative Ring $R$ it states for $a,b,c \in R$ with $a \neq b,
>  a \leq c, b \leq c$ that $$\text{gcd}(a,c)=1 \wedge \text{gcd}(b,c)=1 \Longrightarrow \text{gcd}(a,b)=1.$$

I don't know if this is right in general. I couldn't find a counterexample so my hope is that it's true.

Is there a general proof?

Comment: Have a look at the case $a=b$.

Comment: $\gcd(6,5)=\gcd(12,5)=1$

Comment: $\gcd(5,13)=\gcd(10,13)=1$ but $\gcd(5,10)=5$

Comment: your hypothesis is still not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the ring $\mathbb{Z}$.
Take $c = 7, \; a = 2, \; b = 4$

Then $gcd(2,7) = 1, \; gcd(4, 7) = 1$, but $gcd(2,4) = 2$.
In general this is false.